A strange property about modulus
I came across this strange property :
A = 1365636947370912401969102170896050049833536043036222945024106106365095957448673476595717951882200
B = 1353221295111631852153727244194823890765967481385223615864962219103729677003203245224034685374611



Why $0\notin \{(B \times 11^n \bmod A) \bmod 11 \mathrel: n \in \mathbb N \} = \{ 1,2,3,\dots,10\} \text{?}$
Is there a more general property behind it?



intriguing; will you share a proof for statement 1?

I have not found any counter-examples.

you might need really large $n$, up to $n=10^6$ also 1,2,3 do not appear

the interesting fact is that $(11^n\times B \mod A) \mod 11$, does not take all values ​​between 0 and 10.

How many powers of 11 modulo A are there?

@FedorPetrov The order of $11$ mod $A$ should be $223092870$, I think.

Does this have to do with the sequence of primordial numbers (A002110)? I notice that $(B\times 11^{\rm primordial} \mod A) \mod 11$ is an interesting sequence.

How were these values of $A, B$ found?

By trial and error.

When you type B\mod A it is rendered as $B\mod A$ and when you type B\bmod A it is rendered as $B\bmod A.$ Presumably the "b" stands for "binary". \bmod is to be used when ${\bmod}$ is used as a binary operation symbol.

@DaveBenson $\qquad\uparrow \qquad$

Can someone explain to the rest of us why this is interesting?

@AndrejBauer: In other words, OP claims that the base-11 expansion of the fraction $B/A$ contains only nonzero digits. If the claim is correct, it is a nontrivial construction due to the large period 223092870 of $B/A$ in base 11 with relatively small size of $A,B$. But the question itself sounds like a challenge to the readers to reveal the construction method that OP used.

How exactly does this example qualify as  "relatively small size"?

@DavidLoeffler: $A,B\ll 11^{223092870}.$

@DaveBenson, ha, non-mathematical auto-correct is more familiar with ‘primordial’ than ‘primorial’.

@LSpice Ha! too right. My observation was that the $n$th primorial number is the first time the function returns a number as low as $11-n$, up until $n=10$, but then the tenth primorial number is the order of $11$ mod $A$. This is probably a clue to how the numbers were constructed.

As it was guessed in the comments, the important feature of the given $A$ is that $A$ is composed of prime powers, modulo each of which the multiplicative order of $11$ belongs to the set formed by first 9 primes $p_1=2$, ..., $p_9=23$. Together they give a huge multiplicative order of $11$ modulo $A$ equal the primorial $2\cdot 3\cdots 23=223092870$, and it is the period length of base-11 expansion of the fraction $B/A$. The period itself as an integer is given by
$$T:=B\cdot \frac{11^{223092870}-1}{A}.$$
The "strange property" referred to in the question can be stated as all base-11 digits of $T$ are nonzero.
It may be surprising that one can achieve nonzero digits in the whole period with $A,B$ of relatively small base-11 length (as compared to period length $223092870$), and here I give a possible construction for such numbers. I did not reverse engineer the OP's approach, but I suspect it was something similar.

The idea is to construct $\frac{B}{A}$ as the sum of fractions
$$\sum_{i=1}^9 \frac{N_i}{11^{p_i}-1},$$
where numerators $N_i$ are to be determined and should be coprime to the corresponding denominators.
The period length of base-11 expansion of $\frac{N_i}{11^{p_i}-1}$ is $p_i$, and they are clearly pairwise coprime. Hence, the elements of the resulting period (i.e. the digits of $T$) are the sums of all possible combinations of nine elements taken one from each of these small periods plus a carry, taken modulo 11.
We fix base-11 digits of each of the small periods be from the set $\{9,10\}$, which "magically" gives a fixed carry equal 8, and sum of any nine such digits plus the carry results in the interval $[89,98]$. Note that the numbers in this interval do have a fixed quotient 8 (the carry) from division by 11, while there is no residue 0 modulo 11.
More specifically, we can set
$$N_i := \frac{11^{p_i}-1}{10}\cdot 9 + 1,$$
which have all base-11 digits equal 9, except the last one being 10. They give the following $A,B$ as the denominator and numerator of the fractional part of the sum stated above:
A = 1365636947370912401969102170896050049833536043036222945024106106365095957448673476595717951882200
B = 148979346996371790012285143790831164050922165954621623661554497897875876190337579031255061695809

Just in case, I have computationally verified that the base-11 digits of the corresponding $T$ are nonzero.
